# Recibir parametros de metodo POST

Tags: c#, post

Como puedo cachar los parámetros que una página externa me manda por metodo POST. 
Yo tengo una aplicación en c# que se conecta a una api "X" y dicha api me regresa parámetros pero por un request, a una url que yo le doy, por metodo POST

Comment: Como? la api hace un post a una direccion que le mandas? entonces deberias tener un servicio en esa direccion...

Comment: si, la documentación de la api me dice literal "Se hará un request al campo enviado como ***" y el campo es una url que le mando

Comment: entonces necesitas un servicio de tu lado. de que api hablas que hace semejante ensalada?

Comment: Se llama Presteza Beneficios

Comment: No la conozco. y bueno.. vas a tener que hacer un servicio en ese caso que atienda en esa url que pasaste para poder recibir los parametros. Asi como esta, la pregunta no sirve mucho porque no queda claro que contestarte.

Comment: Me podrías ayudar a formularla adecuadamente, si es posible? por favor

Comment: Tienes que recibir eso en un servicio web, si lo que tienes es puro cliente tendrías que programar eso en un sistema web aparte. Es simple de entender, tú cuando mandas peticiones estás haciendo POST a una URL, ahora te tocará estar del otro lado la petición te la van a hacer a ti.

Comment: Es que los parametros que vienen por post en un request se reciben en tu controlador. Tenes un controlador? Tenes un servicio que atienda una peticion post? que hiciste de todo eso? Que hace tu sistema? que tipo de sistema es?

Comment: realizo un HttpWebRequest request = ** por POST en C#

Comment: HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";

Comment: a la api mencionada y esta me regresa lo que preguntaba

Comment: exacto. tenes que hacer un controler vos. SI no sabes como, esa es tu pregunta. y eso esta en google ;) busca un poco en tu lenguaje preferido, y volve cuando te trabes. Lo que tenes que hacer, es poder recibir una peticion post}

Comment: Que tal, sigo investigando y encuentro ejemplos que servirían en mvc, algo que no mencione es que no lo estoy haciendo en mvc. Y por ende me pierdo cuando me hablan del controlador o controler. Encontre como hacerlo con wcf, voy bien o ya me fui a algo mas complicado?

Comment: ya encontre que puedo hacer un servicio.asmx en visualstudio de esta forma ahí estaría recibiendo el post, pero no me funciona